# Math tutor program wont display "incorrect"

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package chapter5;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = 1;
        int max = 10;
        int one = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        int two = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        int num = (int) (4* Math.random()+1); 
        char operator = 0; 

        switch (num) 
        { 
        case 1: operator = '+'; 
        break; 
        case 2: operator = '-'; 
        break; 
        case 3: operator = '*'; 
        break; 
        case 4: operator = '/'; 
        break;
        }
        System.out.println("What is " + one + " " + operator + " " + two + "?");
        double ans = 0;
        double ans1 = 0;
        ans = input.nextDouble();
        if (num == 1) {
            ans1 = one + two;
        } else {
            if (num == 2) {
                ans1 = one - two;
            } else {
                if (num == 3 ) {
                    ans1 = one * two;
                } else {
                    if (num == 4) {
                        ans1 = one / two;
                    }
                }
            }

        if (ans == ans1) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        } else {
            if (ans != ans1) {
                System.out.println("incorrect");
            }
          }

        }



    }

}
```

So I am trying to create an application that generates a question, and calculates if your input is correct or incorrect, so far from all my tests, when it is correct it displays the correct thing, but when it is incorrect the app terminates.

Comment: hint: try  printing out `ans` and `ans1` to see the difference

Comment: Format your code properly and you will find the reason yourself.

Comment: Its not necessary to use an `if` after or inside else. For example, the section where you check if answer is correct or not, you do not need that `if (ans != ans1)...` inside `else` block. Since you first check if they are equal, the `else` keyword automatically sets condition for if they are unequal. You can eliminate a lot of redundant code in your program if you remove needless if statements inside else blocks. That will make it easier for you to read and walk through your code.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared your code up a little bit, it seems to run fine either way though. Perhaps you should check your editor settings to see if the output console doesn't clear when the program is finished executing.

```
package chapter5;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excercise5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = 1;
        int max = 10;
        int one = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        int two = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        int num = (int) (4 * Math.random()); 

        char operator = "+-/*".charAt(num); 

        System.out.println("What is " + one + " " + operator + " " + two + "?");

        double ans = 0;
        double ans1 = 0;

        ans = input.nextDouble();

        switch(num) {
            case 0:
            ans1 = one + two;
            break;
            case 1:
            ans1 = one - two;
            break;
            case 2:
            ans1 = one / two;
            break;
            case 3:
            ans1 = one * two;
            break;
        }

        if (ans == ans1) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As [Codebender hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558453#comment62605449_37558453), the OP's sloppy coding style isn't just hiding the problem --- it _is_ the problem.  By cleaning up the code, you've accidentally fixed the logic error that was hidden in all those misplaced braces.